# Google Cloud Messaging Group Behaviour

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have some questions about Google Cloud Messaging related to Groups:

1. If I remove all devices from a Group, does the Group gets deleted as well?
2. When I try to add a device to a Group that does not exists, I get  a 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
   "notification_key not found". Is there any specific code for this specific error ? ( So I don't have to compare the string in the response body).
3. When a user deletes the application and reinstall it, his device will be registered twice in the group. In this case, it will receive multiple notifications.
   Whats the best way to fix this behaviour?
4. When a token ( registration_id ) gets expired, does it get removed from the Group?
5. Is there any endpoint to delete a Group using its notification_key?

Comment: 1. I tried deleted all device from the Group, the group seems not get deleted  , when i tried to send the message, it will get `200` and no other string got back. 2. I dont think there is specific code 3. Check here for uninstall https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#how-uninstalled-client-app-unregistration-works 4. i think it not, just `200 + error:NotRegistered` 5. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#adding_and_removing_devices_from_a_device_group

Comment: Your answer for the (3) was really helpful. I still need a more clear explanation for the other ones. The link on (5) explains how to remove devices, but not how to remove the entire Group. Thanks anyway